# Host a PHP application on IIS without WAMP or XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, iis, xampp, wamp

I have developed a PHP application and hosted it in my localhost. The following are the components of localhost.

**PHP - 7.2.14
Wamp Server - 3.1.7
Apache - 2.4.37
PHP MySQL Admin - 5.7.24**

I want to host this application on the server which does not have WAMP/XAMPP. But only has IIS. The following are the components in the Server.

**PHP - 5.2.3
IIS - 7**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "myuser";
$pass = "XXXXXX";
$db = "vehicles3";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if($conn == false){
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
$GLOBALS['conn'] = $conn;
?>
```

When I execute the above code, it shows the following error

```
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2054 Debugging error: Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
```

I have even tried to change the charset and collation in my Server SQL workbench to latin1 and latin_swedish_ci respectively which are the charset and collation of my localhost Database.

Comment: PHP 5.2 has been dead for years. Don't use it.

Comment: Hey, you need to set up a proper php setting in iis and with mysql server and get a simple test within it with <?php phpinfo(); ?> And of course a basic mysql connection. Search at w3school for the basic mysql connection. About the unknown charset YOU NEED TO CREATE A NEW MYSQL USER WITH BASIC AUTH (mysql_native_password). Don't forget to flag my answer if it solves the problem!!

Comment: Have you tried PHP 7？ If change charset not work for IIS, it sounds like a compatibility issue.